# Calculate from 3 inputfield in dynamic form yii2

Tags: yii2

In my dynamic form I need to calculate data from from 3 fields(qty,rate,discount) and pass it to unitdiscount. The formula will be - `unitdiscount = ((qty*rate*discount)/100)` . I already have onchange event(`getValue`) on inputfield qty and rate as I pass `(qty*rate)` to `value`. When I'm adding the new onchange(`getUnitdiscount`), the calcluted field `value` is not passed. In stead, I get `unitdiscount`. Also, not sure how can I calculate from 3 inputdields.

I calculated `value` with the help of [Pass calculated data in a texbox not from any model in dynamic form yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557301/pass-calculated-data-in-a-texbox-not-from-any-model-in-dynamic-form-yii2/40560307?noredirect=1#comment68359021_40560307)

My present code looks like -

_form

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]rate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'onchange' => 'getValue($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getValue($(this))','onchange' => 'getUnitdiscount($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getUnitdiscount($(this))','placeholder' => 'Rate']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]qty")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'onchange' => 'getTotal($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getTotal($(this))','onchange' => 'getValue($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getValue($(this))','onchange' => 'getUnitdiscount($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getUnitdiscount($(this))','placeholder' => 'Qty']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]free")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'onchange' => 'getTotal($(this))', 'onkeyup' => 'getTotal($(this))','placeholder' => 'Free']) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 nopadding">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]discount")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'Discount']) ?>
                                </div> 
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 ">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-value">
                                </div> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-unitdiscount">
```

JS Function

```
<?php
/* start getting the product value */
$script = <<< JS
function getValue(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var total = current = next = 0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if(myString == "qty") {
        fetch = index.concat("-rate");
    } else {
        fetch = index.concat("-qty");
    }

    temp = $("#productsales-"+fetch+"").val();

    if(!isNaN(temp) && temp.length != 0) {
        next = temp;
    }

    current = item.val();
    if(isNaN(current) || current.length == 0) {
        current = 0;
    }

    if(!isNaN(current) && !isNaN(next)) {
        total =parseFloat((parseFloat(current) * parseFloat(next))).toFixed(2);
    }

    valueField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-value");

    $("#"+valueField+"").val(total);
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/* end getting the product value */
?>
<?php
/* start getting the product Unit discount */
$script = <<< JS
function getUnitdiscount(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var total = current = next = 0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if(myString == "qty") {
        fetch = index.concat("-rate");
    } else {
        fetch = index.concat("-qty");
    }

    temp = $("#productsales-"+fetch+"").val();

    if(!isNaN(temp) && temp.length != 0) {
        next = temp;
    }

    current = item.val();
    if(isNaN(current) || current.length == 0) {
        current = 0;
    }

    if(!isNaN(current) && !isNaN(next)) {
        total =parseFloat((parseFloat(current) * parseFloat(next))).toFixed(2);
    }

    unitdiscountField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-unitdiscount");

    $("#"+unitdiscountField+"").val(total);
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/* end getting the product Unit discount */
?>
```

Update - 
I've changed the inptfields and put `onchange(getUnitdiscount)` in front of onchange(`getUnitdiscount`). Now I'm atleast getting ouput in both textbox `unitdiscount` and `value`.

I've tried with the following javascript which not giving correct result.

```
<?php
/* start getting the total udisc */
$script = <<< JS
function getUdisc(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var total = current = next = previous =0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if(myString == "qty") {
        fetch2 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch1 = index.concat("-rate");
    } else if(myString == "discount") {
        fetch3 = index.concat("-qty");
        fetch1 = index.concat("-rate");
    } else {
        fetch2 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch3 = index.concat("-qty");
    }

    temp = $("#productsales-"+fetch1+"").val();

    if(!isNaN(temp) && temp.length != 0) {
        next = temp;
    }

    current = item.val();
    if(isNaN(current) || current.length == 0) {
        current = 0;
    }

    previous = item.val();
    if(isNaN(previous) || previous.length == 0) {
        previous = 0;
    }

    if(!isNaN(current) && !isNaN(next) && !isNaN(previous)) {
        total = parseFloat(current) + parseFloat(next) + parseFloat(previous);
    }

    udiscField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-udisc");

    $("#"+udiscField+"").val(total);
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/* end getting the total udisc */
?>
```

By this javascript if I put `rate = 50.50`, `qty = 100`, `discount = 10` it should give result `160.50` but it's giving `70.50`. (I've taken a simple formula as `unitdiscount = rate + qty + discount` to test if I am getting the values correctly, then I can change the formula to a complex one.)

Comment: Try `(parseFloat(50.50) + parseFloat(100) + parseFloat(10)).toFixed(2);`

Comment: It is giving 160.50 as soon as I type any digit in rate,qty and discount even 0,0,0. I mean what would be the javascript part to take it dynamically?

Comment: You mean get textbox value?

Comment: Yes get the values from textboxes rate, qty and discount  -- calculate the sum of these three. I've wrote the javascript part based on the work we previously done. There might be something wrong in it.

Comment: Dude, get other two textbox value, that's difficult?!!.  I will write solution when get time.

Comment: I've written as above sir, but not quite sure. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
function getUdisc(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var total = current = next = previous = 0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if (myString == "qty") {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-rate");
    } else if (myString == "discount") {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-qty");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-rate");
    } else {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-qty");
    }

    temp1 = $("#productsales-"+fetch1+"").val();
    temp2 = $("#productsales-"+fetch2+"").val();

    if (!isNaN(temp1) && temp1.length != 0) {
        next = temp1;
    }

    if (isNaN(temp2) || temp2.length == 0) {
        previous = temp2;
    }

    current = item.val();
    if (isNaN(current) || current.length == 0) {
        current = 0;
    }

    if (!isNaN(current) && !isNaN(next) && !isNaN(previous)) {
        total = (parseFloat(current) + parseFloat(next) + parseFloat(previous)).toFixed(2);
    }

    udiscField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-udisc");

    $("#"+udiscField+"").val(total);
}
```