# How to calculate taking input from four fields in yii2 dynamic form

Tags: yii2

I've five fields- rate, qty. discount, cgst_percent, cgst_amount.
I want to calculate cgst_amount. The formula should be -

```
cgst_amount = ((rate*qty - (rate*qty*discount)/100)*cgst_percent)/100
```

To Start with simple steps, I tried `cgst_amount = rate*qty`

The javascript part is as below -

```
<?php
/* start getting the cgst */
$script = <<< JS
function getGst(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var qtyvar = ratevar = discvar = cgstpercentvar = cgstvar = 0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if (myString == "rate") {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-qty");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch3 = index.concat("-cgst_rate");
    } else if (myString == "qty") {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-rate");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-discount");
        fetch3 = index.concat("-cgst_rate");
    } else if (myString == "discount"){
        fetch1 = index.concat("-qty");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-rate");
        fetch3 = index.concat("-cgst_rate");
    } else {
        fetch1 = index.concat("-qty");
        fetch2 = index.concat("-rate");
        fetch3 = index.concat("-discount");
    }

    temp1 = $("#productsales-"+fetch1+"").val();
    temp2 = $("#productsales-"+fetch2+"").val();
    temp3 = $("#productsales-"+fetch3+"").val();
    //alert (temp2);

    if (!isNaN(temp1) && temp1.length != 0) {
        ratevar = temp1;
    }

    if (isNaN(temp2) || temp2.length != 0) {
        discvar = temp2;
    }

    if (isNaN(temp3) || temp3.length != 0) {
        cgstpercentvar = temp3;
    }

    qtyvar = item.val();
    if (isNaN(qtyvar) || qtyvar.length == 0) {
        qtyvar = 0;
    }
    //alert (qtyvar);
    if (!isNaN(qtyvar) && !isNaN(ratevar) && !isNaN(discvar) && !isNaN(cgstpercentvar)) {
        cgstvar = (parseFloat(qtyvar) * parseFloat(ratevar)).toFixed(2);

    }

    cgstField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-cgst_amount");

    $("#"+cgstField+"").val(cgstvar);

}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/* end getting the cgst */
?>
```

Whn I key in rate and qty I get multiply of them as output in cgst_amount textbox. No problem so far. As soon as I key in anything in discount,the same texts are getting written in cgst_amount as output.

[image]
I'm not quite sure about the javascript part.
It is an extension of - [Calculate from 3 inputfield in dynamic form yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570683/calculate-from-3-inputfield-in-dynamic-form-yii2) and [Calculate 3 fields and display the result in the 4th in yii2 dynamic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908640/calculate-3-fields-and-display-the-result-in-the-4th-in-yii2-dynamic-form)

If I work on the full formula, the javascript calculation part becomes - `cgstvar = ((((parseFloat(ratevar) * parseFloat(qtyvar)) - (parseFloat(ratevar) * parseFloat(qtyvar) * parseFloat(discvar))/100) * parseFloat(cgstpercentvar))/100).toFixed(2);`

And the example is as below image - 
[image]

The actual result should have been - 5.43. Instead I'm getting -0.00

Comment: What is exact amount after this `((rate*qty - (rate*qty*discount)/100)*cgst_percent)/100)` formula? Update with example and what you get after applying above formula?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of the full calculation formula.

Comment: I will post an update soon when get time.

Comment: Thanks. Please post when you get time,

Answer (score 0):

You meshed up with fields and variables, i have updated a script a bit :

```
function getGst(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var qtyvar = ratevar = discvar = cgstpercentvar = cgstvar = 0;

    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    quantity = index.concat("-qty");
    rate = index.concat("-rate");
    discount = index.concat("-discount");
    cgstRate = index.concat("-cgst_rate");

    temp1 = $("#productsales-"+quantity+"").val();
    temp2 = $("#productsales-"+rate+"").val();
    temp3 = $("#productsales-"+discount+"").val();
    temp4 = $("#productsales-"+cgstRate+"").val();

    if (isNaN(temp1) || temp1.length != 0) {
        qtyvar = temp1;
    }

    if (!isNaN(temp2) && temp2.length != 0) {
        ratevar = temp2;
    }

    if (isNaN(temp3) || temp3.length != 0) {
        discvar = temp3;
    }

    if (isNaN(temp4) || temp4.length != 0) {
        cgstpercentvar = temp4;
    }

    if (!isNaN(qtyvar) && !isNaN(ratevar) && !isNaN(discvar) && !isNaN(cgstpercentvar)) {
        cgstvar = ((((parseFloat(ratevar) * parseFloat(qtyvar)) - (parseFloat(ratevar) * parseFloat(qtyvar) * parseFloat(discvar))/100) * parseFloat(cgstpercentvar))/100).toFixed(2);
    }

    cgstField = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-cgst_amount");

    $("#"+cgstField+"").val(cgstvar);

}
```