# Calculate Multiple Input Value Depend On Dropdown Value Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I am litle bit crazy about this form. I use yii2 dynamic form wbraganca to clone my form. I want to sum multiple form separately base on dropdown value, but what I get is sum all the value.

This is my form :

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_manifest', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-manifest', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item-manifest', // required: css class
    //'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item-manifest', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item-manifest', // css class
    'model' => $modelManifest[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'id_keagenan',
        'jenis_manifest',
        'jlh_manifest',
    ],
]); ?>
<div class="container-manifest"><!-- widgetContainer -->
<?php foreach ($modelManifest as $i => $modelManifest): ?>
    <div class="item-manifest panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Manifest Keagenan</h3>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="add-item-manifest btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="remove-item-manifest btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
                // necessary for update action.
                if (! $modelManifest->isNewRecord) {
                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelManifest, "[{$i}]id");
                }
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php echo $form->field($modelManifest, "[{$i}]id_keagenan")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Keagenan::find()->all(), 'id_keagenan', 'nama_keagenan'),
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'theme' => Select2::THEME_KRAJEE,
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Keagenan --', 'class' => 'form-control'],
                    ]); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelManifest, "[{$i}]jlh_manifest")->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
                        [
                            'clientOptions' => [
                                'alias' => 'numeric',
                                'groupSeparator' => '.',
                                'digits' => 0,
                                'autoGroup' => true,
                                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                                'rightAlign' => false,                                                                  
                            ],
                            'options' => [
                                'class' => 'form-control manifest',
                                'maxlength' => true,
                            ]                                                               
                        ])
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?= $form->field($modelManifest, "[{$i}]jenis_manifest")->dropDownList([ 'Berangkat' => 'Berangkat', 'Pulang' => 'Pulang'], ['class' => 'jenis_manifest form-control', 'prompt' => '-- Manifest --']) ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
```

What I want is when I chose `jenis_manifest`, the function is only get `jlh_manifest` base on `jenis_manifest` value.

This is my script which is get all value.

```
$(".container-manifest").on("change", ".jenis_manifest", function() {
    var jenis_manifest = $(".jenis_manifest").val();
    if(jenis_manifest == "Berangkat")
    {
        var items = $(".item-manifest");
        var sum = 0;

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var manifest = $(elem).find(".manifest").val().replace(/,/g , "");
            sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(manifest);
        });

        $("#jlh_semua_manifest_berangkat").val(sum);
    }
    else if(jenis_manifest == "Pulang")
    {
        var items = $(".item-manifest");
        var sum = 0;

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var manifest = $(elem).find(".manifest").val().replace(/,/g , "");
            sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(manifest);
        });

        $("#jlh_semua_manifest_pulang").val(sum);
    }
});
```

**Update**

This is the screenshot

[image]

The result what I want is :

- Berangkat + Berangkat = 500000 + 1500000 = 2000000
- Pulang = 500000

But what I get with my script is :

Berangkat + Berangkat + Pulang = 500000 + 1500000 + 500000 = 2500000

Comment: Quite unclear, add screen-shot of your form, what you exactly want to accomplish?

Comment: I suggest you to use `#id` selector instead of `.class` selector. See my previous answers on [dynamic-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966001/how-to-calculate-taking-input-from-four-fields-in-yii2-dynamic-form/44989371#44989371)

Comment: so I must call the function when dropdown value change? but when I call the function directly `'onchange' => 'getGst($(this));'` , it get error `getGst() is not defined`. where I suppose to put the function? inside `create.php` or direct on `_form.php` ??

Comment: In `_form.php`  it's not necessary to call a function but if you want to fetch value but you need id to separate each field and yes `getGst()` not applicable in your code, check only jquery part How to get id from selected element.

Comment: yes, I need to fetch the value, so I call the function directly like this..
`<?= $form->field($modelManifest, "[{$i}]jenis_manifest")->dropDownList([ 'Berangkat' => 'Berangkat', 'Pulang' => 'Pulang'], ['class' => 'jenis_manifest form-control', 'prompt' => '-- Manifest --', 'onchange' => 'getFunction("Halo")']) ?>` just test, but I got error `Reference error getFunction is not defined`

Comment: your js not registered properly.