# wbraganca yii2 dynamic form date picker issue?

Tags: javascript, yii2, uidatepicker, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform

I am using wbraganca dynamic form. In my form one field need date picker,so i use jui date picker like below

```
<?= $form->field($model, "[{$i}]DOB")->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                         'language' => 'en',
                         'options' => ['class'=>'cust-form-control dob','placeholder'=>'Date of birth','autocomplete'=>'off','readOnly'=>true,'aria-label' => 'Date of Birth'],
                          'clientOptions'=>[
                            'changeMonth'=>true,
                            'changeYear'=> true,
                            'yearRange'=> "1925:+0",
                            'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
                            'maxDate' => "-1D",
                          ],
                    ])->label(false); ?>
```

Earlier i am face one problem, that is the date picker open only first form, if user click add button means the form will appear but datepicker does not appear, so i am add one custom script like below

```
$(function () {
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
     $( ".dob" ).each(function() {
        $( this ).datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange : '1925:+0',
        maxDate : '-1D',
        language : 'en',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
      });
    });          
});
```

});

So date picker open all forms correctly and i am open multiple form and choose date picker one by one means it is working fine. But problem is for example, First i am open two forms and close first form, now the second form come first at that time date picker will appear but it is not clickable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457408/select2-and-depdrop-in-dynamic-form-in-yii2/40468025#40468025

Comment: Working on it, will update when get some luck.

Comment: thank u and firebug i got this error /uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `afterDelete` and reinitialize datepicker :

```
$this->registerJs(' 
$(function () {
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
        $( ".dob" ).each(function() {
           $( this ).datepicker({
              dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
              yearRange : "1925:+0",
              maxDate : "-1D",
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
           });
      });          
    });
});
$(function () {
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e, item) {
        $( ".dob" ).each(function() {
           $( this ).removeClass("hasDatepicker").datepicker({
              dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
              yearRange : "1925:+0",
              maxDate : "-1D",
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
           });
      });          
    });
});
');
```

You [need to remove](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-ui/upJF4_W-3rk)  class `hasDatepicker` to reinitialize datepicker.

Comment: thank u so much.Insane Skull,i have tried last three days again thank u so much