# DatePicker only working on 1st row of Dynamic Form in Yii2

Tags: datepicker, yii2, dynamicform

I'm using wbraganca dynamic-form. The problem I'am facing is that datepicker works fine for the first row of dynamic form. But on rest of the rows its not working. I have tried almost every possible solution for it but none of them worked for me.

The first alteration I did to code is by making changes in yii2-dynamic-form.js by replacing the code below

```html
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
        var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-datepicker]');
        var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-datepicker]');
        if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
            $hasDatepicker.each(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeData().datepicker('remove');
                $(this).parent().datepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-datepicker')));
            });
        }
```

with this

```html
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
       var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-kvdatepicker]');
    if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
     $hasDatepicker.each(function() {
     $(this).parent().removeData().kvDatepicker('remove');
     $(this).parent().kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));
    });
   }
```

and now it is showing an error in the console as below

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deprecated' of undefined
    at Datepicker.remove (bootstrap-datepicker.js:33)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datepicker.js:1649)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
    at jQuery.fn.init.datepickerPlugin [as kvDatepicker] (bootstrap-datepicker.js:1626)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (yii2-dynamic-form.js:316)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
    at _restoreSpecialJs (yii2-dynamic-form.js:315)
    at _addItem (yii2-dynamic-form.js:116)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651844/wbraganca-yii2-dynamic-form-date-picker-issue

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I was struggling for hours and finally came up with a simple solution, sometimes it is better to figure up a solution from your experience rather than searching for hours.

I did same as you did but then I made this simple modification

```
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
    var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-kvdatepicker]');
    if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
        $hasDatepicker.each(function () {
//      $(this).parent().removeData().kvDatepicker('remove');
// here is the solution
$(this).parent().find('.krajee-datepicker').kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));


        });
    }
```

Jus catch the input that has .krajee-datepicker class and initialize it with KvDatepicker loading to it the options of the first datepicker element you have created.

It worked for me. tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this problem on many embeded dynamic forms and the problem was solved in next way:

1.-Go to folder frontend/web/assets or backend/web/assets and delete all files there (cache files) except .gitignore if you're using git

2.-Go to vendor/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform.js and comment paragraph block

```
    // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
    /*
    var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-datepicker]');
    if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
        $hasDatepicker.each(function() {
            $(this).parent().removeData().datepicker('remove');
            $(this).parent().datepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-datepicker')));
        });
    }
    */
```

3.-Paste next code there

```
    // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
    var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-kvdatepicker]');
    if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
        $hasDatepicker.each(function () {
            console.log("Clonado2....");
            $(this).parent().removeData().off();
            //$(this).parent().removeData().kvDatepicker('remove');
            $(this).parent().kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));
            //$(this).parent().find('.krajee-datepicker').kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));
        });
    }
```

4.-Enjoy ;D

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me, hope it works for other too

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on('afterInsert', function(e, item) {
    var datePickers = $(this).find('[data-krajee-kvdatepicker]');
    datePickers.each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).parent().removeData().kvDatepicker('initDPRemove');
        $(this).parent().kvDatepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-kvdatepicker')));
    });
```

});

Add this code in your view file, and no need to worry about the server code changes for the yii2 dynamic form.